# Xamarin.forms .NetStandard How to play a video?

Tags: c#, xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I currently developing a **Xamarin.form** app that use **.NetStandard** as code sharing technique.
On a certain point in the app, the app must show a video from a url. A video could take **up to 5 minutes**.
I currently can't find a way how I can play a video in my Xamarin.Forms app.
Most of the examples on the web using PCL with .NET Framework.

I tried This plug in, but it isn't fully supported for .NetStandard, since it is written for .Net Framework:
https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

I already managed to play a video on Android and iOs following this tutorial:
https://blog.xamarin.com/delivering-rich-media-experiences-xamarin-forms-video-player/

However, it can only play videos up to 15 seconds for free and in UWP, it seems to be a bit broken.

I simply cannot figure out how I can play a video up to 5 minutes using .Net Standard.

Can someone please explain step by step how I can show a video in a **Xamarin.Form** app using **.NetStandard** as code sharing technique?

Or If anyone could explain in detail how to make my own video control, that works on each platform, that would be fantastic.

Your help is really much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm suffering this very issue

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [LibVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) which provides a netstandard target as well as well native controls for each platforms.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full tutorial how implementing a video(local or web) in your app 
 manually at [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/) 
either there is a [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/VideoPlayerDemos/)

Comment: Thanks for providing those links but this is the exact documentation that states. " However, the current version of VideoPlayer cannot access resources embedded in a .NET Standard library."